# Does $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} = \infty ?$

Tags: calculus

I was curious as to whether  $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}=\infty $$
Or the limit does not exist? Because doesn't a limit exist if and only if the limit tends to a finite number?

Comment: i really like this question! it's getting a lot of attention from lots of people, amateur(like me) and expert. i wonder why this question isn't really that up-voted...

Comment: I believe that most people would say "the limit doesn't exist _because_ it goes to infinity."  There are lots of ways for a limit not to exist, and going to infinity is a special case.  Your displayed equation is correct, but it doesn't say that the limit exists.  I just says that the limit fails to exist in this interesting way.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any $B>0$, $\frac{1}{x^2}>B$ whenever $0<|x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{B}}$. By definition the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Whoops, that was quite silly. Time for a coffee break.

Comment: so it is that as $\lim_{B \to \infty}$,  $\frac {1}{x^2} \to \infty$?

Comment: @AlexanderDay No, that isn't correct.

Comment: @Dr.MV how would it be then?

Comment: @AlexanderDay  For any $B>0$, however large (say $B=1,000,000,000$), we can find a deleted neighborhood $N$ of $0$ for which $x\in N$ implies $1/x^2>B$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a limit exists if the left and right limits exist and agree. Just to clarify, yes, $\infty$ or $-\infty$ are suitable limits.

Since $(-x)^2=x^2,$ then

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{1}{x^2}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{1}{x^2}=\infty,$$
and so you are correct, 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x^2}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is a special case. We write $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$$ to mean:

For all $M\in\mathbb R$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies f(x)>M$.

As you noticed, this is different from the definition used for a finite limit.

Answer (score 1):

"Because doesn't a limit exist if and only if the limit tends to a finite number? "

It's a matter of notation and/or definition.

I'd argue "The limit is infity" and "the limit does not exist" are *NOT* contradictory statements:

.....

The symbols $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty$ means, by definition, for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $M$ so that whenever $|x-a| < \epsilon$, it follows $f(x) > M$. (Colloquially, "as $x$ gets close to $a$, $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily large".)

[Equivalently, for any $M$ no matter how large we can find an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for all $|x - a| < \epsilon$ we will have $f(x) > M$.  That might be a more direct interpretation of our intuitive understanding.]

And that *is* true for the symbols you wrote.

When we write $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$ and $L$ is a finite value, we mean, for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $\delta$ so that whenever $|x-a| < \epsilon$ $|f(x) -L| < \delta$. (Colloquially, "as $x$ gets close to $a$, $f(x)$ gets close to $L$").

Notice neither of these have to be true.  $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin \frac 1x \ne \pm \infty; \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin \frac 1x \ne L$ for any finite $L$.

If there exist such a number we call such a number "the limit as $x\rightarrow a$".  So "the limit is $L$" is meaningful and well defined.

If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty$ it would be true to say "No finite limit exists". It'd even be true to say "No limit exists" as it is understood that a limit is a finite number.

However the sounds "The limit is infinity" are sounds we can produce by exhaling air through our vocal cords. And we can declare:  "That means $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty$".

And that would be just fine.

So the two statements "No limit exists" and "The limit is infinity" are not necessarily inconsistent. Although for personal style you'll probably want to pick one and stick to it.  It should be very clear in context what you mean.  I, personally would use "no limit exists" to mean that neither $\lim f(x) = \pm \infty$ nor $\lim f(x) = L$ I'd say "The function diverges to positive infinity" for $\lim f(x) = \infty$.

.....

At any event.... for any $\epsilon > 0$ there will be an $M$ so that $|x| < \epsilon \implies \frac 1{x^2} > M$. (or for any $M$ we can find an $\epsilon > 0$).

That is true and I believe you understand and thoroughly accept that.

Answer (score 0):

good question. if you have $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}$$

as $x \to 0$, the denominator gets closer to 0, and the number gets bigger. example:

$$\frac {1}{0.01^2}=10000$$
$$\frac {1}{0.001^2}=1000000$$
$$\frac {1}{0.00001^2}=100000000$$

BUT(and this is a big but)  you cannot have division by $0$, but it can be something very very close to it.

you can also have any real number! any number getting to 0 will register as $+\infty$

BUT(yes, another but!) if you use a POSITIVE imaginary number(i.e 4+5i), you'll get to $-\infty$  according to my problem on [negative imaginary numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227924/would-a-negative-imaginary-number-times-an-imaginary-number-be-positive), $-i=i^3$ thus $$(-i^2)=(i^3)^2=i^6=i^2=\sqrt {-1}$$  so a negative imaginary number (i.e. 9-4i)is also tends to $-\infty$

(yet another!)but, i did some more trial and error and found out something else important: in $a+bi$, if $a>b>0$, then the answer will be positive. case in point:

$$[6+4i]^2=[36-16]=20$$

and if you have $a-bi$ and $a<0>b$, then the answer is positive. example:

$$[4-6i]^2=[16-[-36]]=[16+36]=52$$
or
$$[16-3i]^2=[256-[-9]]=[256+9]=265$$

so you could also say that $$\left(\lim_{a \to 0} > \lim_{b \to 0}\right) \frac {1}{a+bi}\to \infty$$

and either $a$ or $b$ can be 0, but **NOT** both.

so you can rewrite the equation for this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by __positive imaginary__ numbers. There is no such thing as greater or smaller in the complex domain, as far as I know.

Comment: Positive need not mean x > 0.  Although, you are correct "positive imaginary" is not clearly defined.  But it could be made to be so.  Alll complex numbers have a Real Component and an Imaginary component both of which are real numbers.  i.e. z = a + bi; Re(z) = a; Im(z) = b.  A "purely imaginary" complex number is one such that the real component is zero.  A "positive imaginary" number could be definined as one where the real component is zero an the imaginary component is positive.

Comment: @fleablood 1) Imaginary is not purely imaginary. 2) I am not convinced with _could be defined_. 3) Alex has used the term as if it was well-defined in mathematics.

Comment: It is defined as I did in many texts but it's not a universal term. As I have defined it, it *is* well-defined.   Imaginary is too purely imaginary.  So nyah-nyah.

Comment: Perhaps, you are right though.  "Positive imginary" can be defined and often is, but amateurs shouldn't as it is is misleading.  I hadn't read Alexander day's question on "negative imaginary numbers" at first, and now that I have it does dislay a dangerous niavite about what "negative" and imaginary mean that should be nipped in the bud. i is not "positive" at all in the usual sense of the term.Positive and negative just won't have any meaning in complex numbers.  i is not real quantity and though it has an absolute measure of 1, complex numbers don't have a binary positive/negative parity.

Comment: Also if we consider x-> 0 in complex numbers x need not "approach" from any of the the standard four directions and it need not go either "$\pm \infty$" (or even $i*\infty $ or $-i*\infty $) but it could be any infinite magnitude with any angle (not just two angles 0 and 180) and it need not consistant go toward any one if them. I'm changing my mind that this answer really doesn't quite address the complex plane properly.